# Read Process Memory in C++

Tags: c++, readprocessmemory

I am coding a hack for an online-game but i have an issue. The value for the address that i want to do is changing everytime i restart the game.

```
void WallShootFunction(bool fEnable)
{
 if(fEnable)
 {
     int value = 0x000000;

            int oo = ReadProcessMemory("S4Client", (LPVOID)value, &value, 4, 0);
            WritePointer(oo, 0x0, 4)

         }
     }
```

I did it like that. The thing i want to do is, i need to add the value +3 everytime, Example if it's orig. value 5, it must be 8. 
Then if its orig. value changes to 7, it must be 10, 17 => 20 etc. How can i do that ? Thanks.

Comment: Is it not simply a matter of an `int` being 4 bytes?

Comment: `I am coding a hack for an online-game`, play fair !

Answer (score 0):

Ok:

1. hacking online games is not considered cool;
2. `ReadProcessMemory` does not return an `int`, nor should it have an `int` as a parameter where you are using them;
3. The first parameter for `ReadProcessMemory` is not the "name" for a process, but a process handle. You'll have to find the handle using `EnumProcesses` etc.